# Writing to a field in a MaybeUninit structure?

Tags: rust, initialization, undefined-behavior, unsafe

I'm doing something with `MaybeUninit` and FFI in Rust that seems to work, but I suspect may be unsound/relying on undefined behavior.

My aim is to have a struct `MoreA` extend a struct `A`, by including `A` as an initial field. And then to call some C code that writes to the struct `A`. And then finalize `MoreA` by filling in its additional fields, based on what's in `A`.

In my application, the additional fields of `MoreA` are all integers, so I don't have to worry about assignments to them dropping the (uninitialized) previous values.

Here's a minimal example:

```rust
use core::fmt::Debug;
use std::mem::MaybeUninit;

#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Debug)]
#[repr(C)]
struct A(i32, i32);

#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Debug)]
#[repr(C)]
struct MoreA {
    head: A,
    more: i32,
}

unsafe fn mock_ffi(p: *mut A) {
    // write doesn't drop previous (uninitialized) occupant of p
    p.write(A(1, 2));
}

fn main() {
    let mut b = MaybeUninit::<MoreA>::uninit();
    unsafe { mock_ffi(b.as_mut_ptr().cast()); }
    let b = unsafe {
        let mut b = b.assume_init();
        b.more = 3;
        b
    };
    assert_eq!(&b, &MoreA { head: A(1, 2), more: 3 });
}
```

Is the code `let b = unsafe { ... }` sound? It runs Ok and [Miri doesn't complain](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=90b889103b2d10c4f4eba6aefb0ff9d6).

But [the `MaybeUninit` docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#initialization-invariant) say:

> Moreover, uninitialized memory is special in that the compiler knows that it does not have
>   a fixed value. This makes it undefined behavior to have uninitialized data in a variable
>   even if that variable has an integer type, which otherwise can hold any fixed bit pattern.

Also, the Rust book says that [Behavior considered undefined](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html) includes:

> - Producing an invalid value, even in private fields and locals. "Producing" a value happens any time a value is assigned to or read from a place, passed to a function/primitive operation or returned from a function/primitive operation. The following values are invalid (at their respective type):
>
>   ... An integer (i*/u*) or ... obtained from uninitialized memory.

On the other hand, it doesn't seem possible to write to the `more` field *before* calling `assume_init`. Later on the same page:

> There is currently no supported way to create a raw pointer or reference to a field of a struct
>   inside MaybeUninit. That means it is not possible to create a struct by calling
>   MaybeUninit::uninit::() and then writing to its fields.

If what I'm doing in the above code example *does* trigger undefined behavior, what would solutions be?

1. I'd like to avoid boxing the A value (that is, I'd like to have it be directly included in `MoreA`).
2. I'd hope also to avoid having to create one `A` to pass to `mock_ffi` and then having to *copy* the results into `MoreA`. `A` in my real application is a large structure.

I guess if there's no sound way to get what I'm after, though, I'd have to choose one of those two fallbacks.

If struct A is of a type that can hold the bit-pattern 0 as a valid value, then I guess a third fallback would be:

3. Start with `MaybeUninit::zeroed()` rather than `MaybeUninit::uninit()`.

Comment: Here's one possibility for the minimal example: replace the current `let b = unsafe { ... }` code with `let b = unsafe { (*b.as_mut_ptr()).more = 3; b.assume_init() }`. The docs on MaybeUninit::as_mut_ptr only say that _reading_ from the pointer or turning it into a ref are undefined, before the struct is initialized. That leaves open that writing to it is ok. (But in my application, that won't work because I need to set the `more` field based on what's in the other fields, so I'd need to read and write.)

Comment: Well, I could start by setting `more` to 0, then call `assume_init`, then mutate the `more` field as needed. So far as I can understand the docs, this should be defined behavior (if my ffi call does indeed initialize the A part of the structure).

Comment: You _can_ initialize a struct field by field, as long as each field is also `MaybeUninit`. Given that your struct is `repr(C)`, you can use an intermediate struct for the purpose and then transmute it. [Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0ea59a743656ec89ef1b83823b0c83d8).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I understand your example. I'd like to know know though why it's not OK to do `unsafe { (*b.as_mut_ptr()).more = 3; b.asume_init() }`, where the `more` field has an int type (so no issues about its being dropped).

Comment: In practice, I _think_ it would be ok, but only because the field is an `i32`. It would be UB if it was a `bool` or most other types.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, the only sound way to refer to uninitialized memory—of any type—is `MaybeUninit`. In practice, it is *probably* safe to read or write to uninitialized integers, but that is not officially documented. It is definitely *not* safe to read or write to an uninitialized `bool` or most other types.

In general, as the documentation states, you cannot initialize a struct field by field. However, it is sound to do so as long as:

1. the struct has `repr(C)`. This is necessary because it prevents Rust from doing clever layout tricks, so that the layout of a field of type `MaybeUninit<T>` remains identical to the layout of a field of type `T`, regardless of its adjacent fields.
2. *every* field is `MaybeUninit`. This lets us `assume_init()` for the entire struct, and then later initialise each field individually.

Given that your struct is already `repr(C)`, you can use an intermediate representation which uses `MaybeIninit` for every field. The `repr(C)` also means that we can transmute between the types once it is initialised, provided that the two structs have the same fields in the same order.

```
use std::mem::{self, MaybeUninit};

#[repr(C)]
struct MoreAConstruct {
    head: MaybeUninit<A>,
    more: MaybeUninit<i32>,
}

let b: MoreA = unsafe {
    // It's OK to assume a struct is initialized when all of its fields are MaybeUninit
    let mut b_construct = MaybeUninit::<MoreAConstruct>::uninit().assume_init();
    mock_ffi(b_construct.head.as_mut_ptr());
    b_construct.more = MaybeUninit::new(3);
    mem::transmute(b_construct)
};
```

Comment: Would it not work, going back to the OP's solution of a single `MaybeUninit<MoreA>` to simply write to the `more` field _before_ calling `assume_init()`? Then by the time `assume_init` is called, all fields have been initialized.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm not convinced that can be done soundly. How do you safely access a field of a `MaybeUninit`?

Comment: By safely, do you mean outside an `unsafe` block, or soundly?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Soundly

Comment: @PeterHall, thanks for your help with this. I just want to add for later reference a few relevant links: [from the nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/unchecked-uninit.html), [rfc 2582](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/64490) on syntax to directly create `*mut <T>`s, and [rust unsafe code guidelines](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/71) on uninitialized ints.

Answer (score 4):

It is now possible (since Rust 1.51) to initialize fields of *any uninitialized struct* using the `std::ptr::addr_of_mut` macro. This example is from the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#initializing-a-struct-field-by-field):

> You can use MaybeUninit, and the std::ptr::addr_of_mut macro, to
> initialize structs field by field:
>
> ```rust
> #[derive(Debug, PartialEq)] pub struct Foo {
>     name: String,
>     list: Vec<u8>, }
>
> let foo = {
>     let mut uninit: MaybeUninit<Foo> = MaybeUninit::uninit();
>     let ptr = uninit.as_mut_ptr();
>
>     // Initializing the `name` field
>     unsafe { addr_of_mut!((*ptr).name).write("Bob".to_string()); }
>
>     // Initializing the `list` field
>     // If there is a panic here, then the `String` in the `name` field leaks.
>     unsafe { addr_of_mut!((*ptr).list).write(vec![0, 1, 2]); }
>
>     // All the fields are initialized, so we call `assume_init` to get an initialized Foo.
>     unsafe { uninit.assume_init() } };
>
> assert_eq!(
>     foo,
>     Foo {
>         name: "Bob".to_string(),
>         list: vec![0, 1, 2]
>     } 
> );
> ```